# How to watch a member of a struct for every struct variable that has that type?

Tags: gdb

I'm getting corruption of a struct member, where struct is used to build a
big tree.  I'm attempting to set a watchpoint, but the "variable" has 
various names (all examples Ive seen use explicit global variables, 
so dont show examples of what Im looking for).

```
(gdb) watch *(OP*)->op.sibling
A syntax error in expression, near `->op.sibling'.
(gdb) watch *(struct op*)->op.sibling
A syntax error in expression, near `->op.sibling'.
(gdb) watch (struct op*)->op.sibling
A syntax error in expression, near `->op.sibling'.
```

the closest I get to acceptable syntax doesnt work

```
(gdb) watch (struct op*)o->op.sibling
No symbol "o" in current context.
```

Is there an expression form that Im missing that would be independent
of the variable name, and attend to the fact that its a particular
kind of structure ?

Would this be able to detect memset overwrites of the struct ?
(even if not, it would help me to rule out some causes)

Is there a gdb reference that goes beyond basic usage ?
(for some defs of 'basic')

Answer (score 14):

As ninjalj says, you do have to have an address to watch; that's the whole point of watchpoints. Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
  long value;
  struct node *next;
} node;

node *build_node(int x, node *next)
{
  node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
  n->value = x;
  n->next = next;
  return n;
}

int main()
{
  node *n = build_node(1, NULL);
  n = build_node(2, n);
  n = build_node(3, n);

  memset(&n->next->value, 0xFF, sizeof(long) + 3);  // corrupt the list

  return 0;
}
```

Here I am generating a list of integers, then corrupt it. Let's see what this looks like in GDB:

```
gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000e0c: file foo.c, line 20.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +. done

Breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:20
20    node *n = build_node(1, NULL);

(gdb) b 26
Breakpoint 2 at 0x100000e8d: file foo.c, line 26.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main () at foo.c:26
26    return 0;
(gdb) p *n
$1 = {
  value = 3, 
  next = 0x100100090
}
(gdb) p *n.next
$2 = {
  value = -1, 
  next = 0x100ffffff
}
```

Here we clearly see that `n->next` as been thoroughly corrupted. Suppose we didn't know where that is happening, and wanted to find out via GDB watchpoint.

First, we need to establish the address that has been corrupted:

```
(gdb) print &n.next.value
$3 = (long int *) 0x100100090
(gdb) watch *$3
Hardware watchpoint 3: *$3
```

Here I just set a watchpoint on address 0x100100090 for 8 bytes.

```
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /private/tmp/a.out 
warning: Could not set watchpoint 3
warning: Could not set watchpoint 3

Breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:20
20    node *n = build_node(1, NULL);
```

I am using a rather old version of GDB, which doesn't understand how to properly disable and re-enable hardware watchpoints across program restart. If you use a more recent version, you'll likely not see above warnings. I can simply re-enable the watchpoint when I am stopped at breakpoint 1:

```
(gdb) enable 3
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: *$3

Old value = 0
New value = 2
build_node (x=2, next=0x100100080) at foo.c:14
14    n->next = next;
```

Ok, we've reached the expected point and the expected value. The next modification will corrupt it, and we want to know where that's happening.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: *$3

Old value = 2
New value = 255
0x00007fff82fae450 in memset ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff82fae450 in memset ()
#1  0x0000000100000ebe in __inline_memset_chk (__dest=0x100100090, __val=255, __len=11) at _string.h:80
#2  0x0000000100000e8d in main () at foo.c:24
```

Voilà, you now know where the unexpected modification comes from.

Answer (score 1):

And how do you expect that to work? gdb watchpoints translate to hardware debug watchpoints where appropiate, i.e. they are memory addresses. So, they're meant to cover regions of memory, not data types.